# checking surrounding cells of an array element java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I need to make a simple(standart) minesweeper for my project.
I want to check the surrounding elements of a random(or specific) element of a 2d array.

lets say I have an array like that

```
boolean board[5][5]
```

I want to check the surrounding elements of

`board[0][0]`

I wrote that:

```
    public int numberChecker(int h, int w) {
    int checker = 0;        
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            int he = h - 1 + i;
            int wi = w - 1 + i;    <---- this i should be j that was the issue
            if (board.getHeight() > he && he >= 0 
                               && wi >= 0 && board.getWidth() > wi) {
            if (boomChecker(he, wi)) {
                if (w != (wi) && h != (he)) {
                    checker++;
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }                                   

    return checker;
}
```

the problem is I think it only checks **" \ "** way (do not know how to put it in words)

ex:

(output # means uncovered numbers mean surrounding mines)

uncover 4-2

```
######
######
0#####
#0####
##0###     <-- unlocking this one
###0##
```

or

uncover 0-0

```
0#####
#0####
##0###
######     <-- there is a mine at check spot
######
######
```

the code itself is not important (I know I made it a bit complicated to explain myself)

all I need is a working surrounding checking for loop (or anything)

thanks in advance

Problem solved 
simple stupid mistake 
                int he = h - 1 + i;
                int wi = w - 1 + i;  <--- i should be j
thanks

Comment: Project? Is that code for `homework`? If so, add a homework tag. Oh, and "\" way is called "diagonal"

Comment: but only \ way diagonal
/ this is also a diagonal thats why i didnt say diagonal :)

Comment: I would describe it using South-East("\") and South-West("/") direction terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your mistake is in this 2 lines:

```
int he = h - 1 + i;
int wi = w - 1 + i;
```

you add to the height AND to the width the value of i. 
So you just check every of the 3 diagonal fields 3 times.
I think it should be

```
int he = h - 1 + i;
int wi = w - 1 + j;
```

so you really iterate through all 9 possible fields and not just through the diagonale.

Hope that helps!

Comment: damn it. that's my 9th simple stupid mistake today. thanks a lot. i need to sleep

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to write my answer as though answering a homework question

now what you really ought to do is, for each cell in your array, there are 8 other cells to check.  so something like:

```
count += board[i-1][j-1] ? 1 : 0;
count += board[i-1][j] ? 1 : 0;
count += board[i-1][j+1] ? 1 : 0;
count += board[i][j-1] ? 1 : 0;
etc.
```

be sure to include some mechanism to prevent you from accessing elements outside the bounds of the array.

also, if you were wondering what the `?` and `:` mean, look up the [Ternary Operator](http://java.about.com/b/2009/06/06/java-term-of-the-week-ternary-operator.htm)  It's useful in all sorts of situations.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you might be better off explicitly checking each of the 8 possible surrounding cells.  It's entirely possible that the JVM might automatically unroll your loop, but I don't see why you wouldn't just check them explicitly.  It will be faster, and easier to understand.

```
boolean upleft = board[row-1][column-1];
boolean up = board[row-1][column];
boolean upright = board[row-1][column+1];
boolean left = board[row][column-1];
boolean right = board[row][column+1];
boolean downleft = board[row+1][column-1];
boolean dow  = board[row+1][column];
boolean downright = board[row+1][column+1];
```

You'll of course have to do bounds checking if your on the edge of the board, but it makes more sense as to what is going on.